# commander - apply false as a default value

Tags: javascript, npm

I am trying to change the default value of [commander](https://www.npmjs.com/package/commander)'s option from true to false. For example:

```
program
    .option('-N, --bundle-number [value]', 'provide bundle version number for generated files')
    .parse(process.argv);
```

If I try to run `command -N` without any value, I am getting true with `program.bundleNumber`, how can I change it to false?

I've tried to pass `false` as a third parameter but it does not work:

```
.option('-N, --bundle-number [value]', 'provide bundle version number for generated files', false)
```

Comment: Try `.option('-N, --bundle-number [value]', 'provide bundle version number for generated files', null, false)`.  The third argument is a function.  The 4th argument is default value.  (although it's supposed to allow a default value as the 3rd argument if it's not a function or RegExp)

Comment: yes now I am getting null as a default value. If I try to change null to false, then I am getting true.